# Отсутствует IndexOutOfRangeException при попытке обратиться к несуществующему индексу строки в unsafe-коде

Tags: c#, строки, unsafe

Почему не вылетает исключение? Как я понимаю, `char*` - непрерывная область памяти из 4 элементов и если я обращаюсь к `[10]`, то обращаюсь к несуществующей ячейки памяти. Но если память выделяется только для 4 элементов, то почему если я обращусь к `p[10]` - то всё будет нормально и выведится `c`.

```
unsafe
{
   string str = "hello";
   fixed(char* p = str)
   {
      p[10] = 'c';
      Console.WriteLine(p[10]); //c
   }
}
```

Comment: А разве `unsafe` не означает как-раз это самое - что вы можете спокойно "стрелять себе в ногу" и `C#` не будет вам в этом никак препятствовать? :)

Comment: @CrazyElf конечно может это и означает, но куда я обращаюсь по индексу 10? Его же не должно существовать

Comment: Эээ, как вы себе представляете хранение данных в компьютере? Островки смысла в великой пустоте? )))  Есть сплошная область памяти, в которой лежат самые разные данные. Одна строка, другая строка, мусор всякий, что угодно. Там, где заканчивается строка, может лежать дальше что угодно, память большая, места много. В случае самых простых кодировок "индекс 10" означает "дай мне содержимое по смещению 10 байт от начала строки" или "20 байт от начала строки" для двухбайтовых кодировок.

Comment: @CrazyElf получается, чисто в теории, если я так буду делать, то однажды изменю например `int` свойство на `char` и получу исключение или что-то другое?

Comment: Что-то вроде того. Хотя тип там не поменяется, поменяются байты. Если эти байты окажутся корректным значением для хранения `int`, то никаких проблем - там будет лежать теперь другое значение  `int`. Байтам всё-равно что хранить, типы возникают, когда к ним обращаются из высокоуровневого языка и тогда надо смотреть, в каком формате какие типы хранит `C#`, в какое именно место и какие байты вы записали.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`p[10]` - это адрес `p` + 20 байт (каждый элемент `char*` = 2 байта), это не индекс в массиве, не путайте.

Вот смотрите

```cs
int a = ~0;
byte* ptr = (byte*)&a;
byte x = ptr[3];
Console.WriteLine(x); // 255
```

Здесь вообще нет массива.

В лучшем случае при попытке читать или писать область памяти за пределами индекса, вы попадете на невыделенную текущему приложению память и получите исключение `AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory.`.

Если еще раз повезёт, вы попадете в свободную область памяти, не выделенную под хранение данных, но выделенную вашему приложению, тогда при создании очередной переменной данные в этой области могут быть перезаписаны, и то что вы туда положили - потеряно.

А вот если не повезет, вы просто повредите данные в других переменных или вообще сломаете экземпляр другого класса, например сейчас вы повредили данные, а приложение упадет через минуту совсем в другом месте по какой-то непонятной причине.

Поэтому, код небезопасный, вы можете творить что угодно, но это так же означает, что ответственность за целостность данных лежит не на компиляторе, а на вас лично.

Кстати, как вам такое?

```cs
string text = "hello";
fixed (char* ptr = text)
{
    int* iPtr = (int*)ptr;
    Console.WriteLine(iPtr[-1]); // 5
}
```

Да, это та самая длина строки `text.Length`. Уж отрицательных то индексов вы точно не видели. `iPtr[-1]` здесь адрес начала данных строки -4 байта, потому что `int` - это 4 байта.

Другими словами, запись адреса памяти `ptr[i]` - это краткий эквивалент записи `*(ptr + i)`.

Comment: А как узнать сколько памяти выделяется приложению? Ее можно как-нибудь искуственно изменить?

Comment: @Aarnihauta за память отвечает GC.